# How to get random keys in Redis

Tags: redis

Is it possible to get 10 random keys in Redis? The 'RANDOMKEY' returns only one random key, I need 10 random keys without running 10 'RANDOMKEY' command.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: why not call `RANDOMKEY` any number of times that you want?

Comment: Might want to reduce RTT.

Comment: Could be pipelined @for_stack though

Comment: @ItamarHaber Yes, pipeline can reduce RTT too :) Also with pipeline, we need to remove duplicate items on the client side.

Comment: Deduping should be also a part of your Lua script following the same rational btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval):

```
local res={}
for i = 1,3 do
    res[i] = redis.call("randomkey")
end

return res
```

If you want to ensure the returned keys are unique, you need to remove duplicate items in the script. I'll leave that as an exercise.